# Why doesn't Java have method delegates?

Tags: c#, java, delegates

The Java gurunaths (natha नाथ = sanskrit for deity-master-protector) at Sun should condescend to accept the necessity of delegates and draft it into Java spec.

In C#, I can pass a method as a handler referenced as a delegate, without needing to go thro the trouble of creating a class just because I need to pass a method in Java.

What are the reasons that make it unnecessary (besides citing the clunky use of a brand new class for the purpose) or disadvantageous that Sun decided not to have it in Java? What advantages does creating a class or implementing interfaces anonymously have over delegates? I can't think of any, can you?

Comment: I updated the title of your question, because "Java should have method delegates" sounded bad

Comment: Many were increasingly of the opinion that they'd all made a big mistake in not having delegates in the first place. And some said that even the delegates would have been a bad move, and that no one should ever consider functions as second-class objects.

Comment: @bozho if you're going to change the title of someone's post, you should be very careful with grammar. I don't mean to be a grammar nazi, but you make him look bad (although the intent of your edit was good)

Comment: thanks.
When I edit something, I indicated it with a comment, so that it's obvious it's my 'fault' :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is [Tom Ball's account](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/08/25/are-closures-just-delegates) for Microsoft proposal to add them to Java and why Sun rejected them.

IMO, Java should have had closures twelve years back. [Gilad Bracha argued](http://blogs.oracle.com/gbracha/entry/achieving_closure) for closures and no one listened. In his own words:

> I personally argued for adding closures since 1997/98. My blood 
>       pressure still rises measurably when I recall the response I got 
>       at the time: "Our customers aren't asking for it, so why add it?".

Sad, but true.

Comment: "should" in such cases should go with "IMO". I haven't met the need for closures - that said, I don't think it should have had them.

Comment: @Bozho Your comments are duly noted. We can agree to disagree on having them in Java. In my view, closures and lambda expressions are essential to a language. Slots of an object can either have data (field) or code (function).

Comment: -1 Delegates encouarge and allow to much bad software design and this is not recognized enough.

Comment: @eaglestorm - Is it possible to provide a backup to your comment?

Comment: The official Sun position http://java.sun.com/docs/white/delegates.html relating to J++ back in the day I think there is also an article by Gosling himself somewhere.

Comment: And now Java does have closures it's called Groovy :)

Comment: @eaglestorm, I read Sun's article and it's kinda' crap.
Basically, what they say is that Java & the Java VM aren't built for non-conservative & modern approaches (delegates, LINQ, etc...)

"Any use of a bound method reference to a private method can be transformed, in a simple and purely local way, into an equivalent program using a one-member private class"

And I say... any use of code can be transformed to an equivalent one written in Assembler, and it would be a lot more efficient too, so why bother yourself with all these high-level language nonsense...?

Comment: @Moshe Itay and Mehrdad give a good explanation of why it's not a good idea.  So your saying you knew better than the whole sun java dev team?

Comment: @eaglestorm, according to your logic, either Microsoft or Sun / Oracle don't know what they're doing? Waiting half a century before making those *very necessary* enhancements, is that your solution...?

The Java platform is outdated for quite some time now.
You can debate as much as you want about the philosophy behind those decisions, but in practice, it's far easier to develop under the .NET platform ever since .NET 3.5 was introduced to the world.

Answer (score 15):

[Minor edits]

Let me first say that I'm not against or in favor of adding delegates to Java. I'm just explaining the background.

First, Sun's Java team has been traditionally more conservative (compared to the C# team) regarding evolution of the language.

Second, Adding a delegate construct into Java would probably require the introduction of a new keyword, such as: "delegate". This will break existing code in which there are variables named "delegate".

Third, there is this design principle called the "Single Choice Principle" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_choice_principle. When applied to language design it means that a programmer should have only one obvious way to achieve something. Or, in other words, multiple choices are risky. The introduction of delegates into Java will work against this principle as their behavior can be achieved via anonymous classes.

[Of course, this principle should not be taken literally. If it were then we'd be programming with a good old Turing Machine. I guess the Sun guys felt that delegates do not constitute a benefit that outweighs the single choice violation]

Comment: +1 for the "Single Choice Principle". I have admired the simplicity of Java artifacts and it's byte code representation. You have articulated the idea very well.

Comment: "If it were then we'd be programming with a good old Turing Machine."  Actually, Turing machine has never been considered to be a practical hardware model or programming model.  Its real purpose is as model for proving certain mathematical results in computation theory.

Comment: -1 for not possible to add keyword. You can add context-sensitive keywords without breaking existing code (or just use a fancy operator, as the colon in the foreach loop).

Comment: I think the Java team is more conservative because they've been in business a lot longer.  Backwards compatibility has been a high priority.  Perhaps they value it more than the captive audience that Microsoft has.

Answer (score 6):

#### Simplicity.

By not introducing the concept of delegates into Java, they made the language simpler. Just like not having properties, indexers, ....

(using a simpler language is not necessarily simpler by the way; probably they should have added delegates but that's not how they made the design decisions)

Comment: Not having delegates is making my projects complex and bulkier with anonymous classes and extraneous interfaces all over the place.

Comment: in that case, perhaps your object-oriented design is not quite good?

Comment: @h2g2java: In my *purely personal* opinion (disclaimer: my favorite language is C#), I agree with you and I think Java is designed so religiously to be "pure". They sacrificed ease of use too much for the purity and simplicity of the language. However, some people (like the designers) definitely disagree. After all, designing a language is hard and you should make a lot of trade-offs. If you add any possible feature to a language, you'll end up reinventing C++ ;).

Comment: h2g2java: You should take into account that C# was developed 2001 while Java is from 1995, and people learned something in that time.

Comment: @Bozho: Perhaps a pure object oriented design is not the best way to solve a problem and a functional paradigm works better. After all, we the ultimate goal of OOP principles is to create better software, not to blindly follow them all.

Comment: that's quite correct, but _maybe_ using functional techniques looks like "the easy path", while the proper one (the one making the software better in terms of maintainability, readability, stability) lies in the OOP realm; a design pattern perhaps.

Comment: Readability? Maintainability? Really?

Anonymous classes are evil - they are everything a code should not be and good developers do their best to avoid it.

Inner classes are step daughters of the anonymous class.
Instead of easily describing the design pattern you use, the Delegate pattern in our case, you're busy writing technical code that does good to no one.

Comment: Once again, I should clarify... what I mean here is that *if you ask the designers*, they will probably come up with "simplicity" and "purity" arguments. Yes, I, too, think they are wrong and it was a mistake not to add it.

Answer (score 4):

java does not have closures because it was not intended to be a functional language, but an object oriented one.
as in many case you can fake another language paradigm, in this case using anonymous interfaces instead of closures.
but now things are changing and under the pressure of new jvm languages like scala, groovy, jruby, etc., that combines oo and funcional paradigms, the java committee is trying to put closures into java 7.

Comment: I believe closures *will* now go into Java 7, after some committee indecision

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you have [inner classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), which are tied to one particular instance of the parent class and have direct access to its members. Thus, implementing an inner class does not require (much) more code than writing a method.

C# does not have inner classes. Both **inner classes** (like in Java) and **delegates** (like in C#) have their advantages (sometimes I miss inner classes in C#), but from a language designer point of view it makes sense to stick to either one of them (rather than supporting both), since this makes the class library design more consistent.

Comment: But you can have nested classes in C#, and they can also access private members of their parent class.

Comment: @Groo: AFAIK, no. The nested class (C#) doesn't automatically get a reference to the parent class. You should pass it explicitly.

Comment: Exactly. Nested class != inner class. A nested class in C# corresponds to a "static nested class" in Java; see the link behind "inner classes" in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because, they thought that:

> *Bound method references [delegates] are simply unnecessary. [...] Moreover, they detract from the simplicity and unity of the Java language. Bound method references are not the right path for future language evolution.*

Taken from this ( old ) white paper:

http://java.sun.com/docs/white/delegates.html

Now Java is considering adding them, once the language have evolved enough. I'm pretty sure they will be in the language soon ( at least sooner than Perl 6 :P )

You can also use: [Software Monkey Callback method](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/Callback)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because if a method is to be passed and shared across objects, it shouldn't be owned by one single class. It should probably be shared via its own class. I mean, a transient function does feel a bit odd if you think of it. Bad OO I suppose.

I REALLY like delegates for UI work. It makes window actions so much easier to program.

It may come down to what you think is more negative, a function that has the wrong owner, or (in my case anyway) your code having methods that belong to one class (button clicks, window resize events) not being part of that one class.

Not sure which I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, I have implemented callback/delegate support in Java using reflection.  Details and working source are [available on my website](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/Callback).

Answer (score -2):

Delegates in C# look ugly to me. (declaring something as variable, and then adding `()` after it feels bad in OOP)

Besides, if you want : "The delegate object can then be passed to code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at compile time which method will be invoked.

you can simply use `java.lang.reflect.Method`

Edit: As you said, using reflection is not a good approach. This is true, but using delegates, in an OOP perspective, is not a better approach, in my opinion. It is a functional-language construct.

Comment: if the downvote is because of the 'offensive' word 'ugly', tell me, I'll change it to "not-beautiful" ;)

Comment: I did not downvote anyone, but reflection as we all know should be used as a last resort.

Comment: I agree on that, but it is as OOP-less as delegates are.

Comment: Many other languages regard functions as object, so declaring a method signature as a type should not be felt as bad OPP. It's like saying you don't like the `::` before the variable names in Fortran when you need multiple attributes.

Comment: java also regards _methods_ as objects, as I noted in my answer. But relying heavily on those is not a good practice.